# Google visualisation - Chart table add column with chart line

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-visualization

I'm actually working with the google visualisation API for a google app engine.
The API works great to build values table, here is the javascript that I use :

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
       
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');      
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: false, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
```

But do you think it is possible to add a column which type is a new chart ? For example : data.addColumn('Chart line', 'Graphic Title');

Thanks,

Comment: There is no support for adding a chart to the table cells, at least not directly.  You could enable html, set each cell to a div with a unique id, and then after the table is drawn, iterate through the divs and draw a line chart in each. You'd want to specify a different table for each, so look into DataView.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the idea. I will try to add them to a HTML table